# handleOpenURL only works when app is already launched, crashes when app is closed

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, url-scheme

I am using URL Schemes to be able to open my app using a url. It is working fine when the receiver app is *running*.

The problem however, is if the app is *closed*. If I type in the url into Safari for example, the app launches and immediately crashes and I'm given:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGKILL"

I have put an NSLog in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions but it looks like that never gets fired, neither does handleOpenURL.

Why does it do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest two things:

1. In XCode 4 - select the Product->Edit Scheme menu and then in the info tab set the Launch radio button to wait for your app to launch.
2. In the arguments tab under Enviornment Variables - enter the NSZombieEnabled with value YES.

Then - I'd launch the app from XCode and it will wait until you enter the URL in Safari. At this point you're in the debugger and you might be able to get more information.

When this happens to me it's usually some memory thing that I haven't properly initialized in one of the code execution paths.

Lastly -if this is happening on a device (not just in the simulator) sometimes there is more information in the Organizer's console.

Comment: The problem was running it on the simulator. Testing the app on the device worked fine.